# How to specify a default perspective?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am developing a plugin with several custom perspectives. So I would like to open one by default on start.

I override `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor#getInitialWindowPerspectiveId` after that specified the same perspective ID in the file `plugin_customization.ini` like this `org.eclipse.ui/defaultPerspectiveId=myPerspectiveId` but it does not help. Each time Eclipse opens last visited perspective.

Only if I specified in the run configuration program arguments `-perspective myPerspectiveId` it works as expected.

How fix that without using program arguments? (for Eclipse Mars)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to force Eclipse to open in the default perspective?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604267/is-there-a-way-to-force-eclipse-to-open-in-the-default-perspective)

Comment: nope, it is different

Comment: Did you mean `WorkbenchAdvisor`? There is no `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor#getInitialWindowPerspectiveId()`.

Comment: Eclipse restores the perspective that was active before the last shutdown. If you want to show the same perspective with each start, you will have to leverage this mechanism. Did you try to set the desired perspective in WorkbenchWindowAdvisor#postWindowRestore()`?