# Eclipse product set default perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm creating Eclipse product and would like to set my own perspective by default opening after workspace launching. I saw that it can be solved via setting this parameter:

```
-perspective ID
```

but I can't understand where to set this parameter. I tried to set it into VM arguments and to Program Arguments, but it didn't help me at all. I saw these questions on the SO : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488335/wheres-the-best-place-to-set-rcp-perspective-during-start-up), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897495/how-to-specify-a-default-perspective), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604267/is-there-a-way-to-force-eclipse-to-open-in-the-default-perspective), [article_1](https://enterprisesmartapps.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/making-a-eclipse-rcprap-application-with-multiple-perspectives/) and [article_2](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/142501/). Maybe I did smth wrong? But I still can't find any solution for this problem.

Comment: Most of those links are about setting the default perspective which is used the first time the workspace is used. `-perspective id` would go in the Program Arguments. The doc seems to say it only works for a RCP using org.eclipse.ui.workbench - so not an e4 RCP.

Comment: The recommended way to set the default perspective is via the `plugin_customization.ini` file with `org.eclipse.ui/defaultPerspectiveId=...`, see e.g. [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java/plugin_customization.ini#n11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`-perspective <id>`](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) should work in *Program Arguments*, but the recommended way to set the default perspective is via the `plugin_customization.ini` file with

```
org.eclipse.ui/defaultPerspectiveId=...
```

See for example, [how it is done in the Java IDE package](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java/plugin_customization.ini?id=9fb6f8314ffee0d90bde609499a03360689a660b#n11).